# Verifying the size of a sub directory

Tags: python

I want to write a shell script that aims to traverse a root directory `C:\xyz` 
and find whether a sub directory `"Demo"` is available in any directories or not. 
If `"Demo"` is available & not empty, print `'OK'`, if `"Demo"` directory is empty, print `'NOT_OK'`.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what issues have you run into

Comment: Your question is not valid and wrongly tagged as `python` instead of `shell script`

Answer (score 0):

To see if there are any directories in folder `xyz` 
that contains another directory named `'Demo'`,
 and if so, whether or not `'Demo'` is empty, you can use the `glob` module

```
from glob import glob

if glob("C:\\xyz\\**\\Demo\\*", recursive=True):
        print("OK")
else:
        print("NOT_OK")
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually misread your first sentence. Still, you might make it more explicit that there _has_ to be _exactly one_ directory in between root and Demo

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you want a Python script to be executed in the terminal and not an actual shell script)

You can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.walk) to recursively list all the files and subdirectories in a given directory. This creates a generator with items in the form `("path/from/root", [directories], [files])` which you can then check whether `any` of those (a) is the desired `Demo` directory, and (b) is not empty.

```
import os
exists_and_not_empty = any(path.endswith("/Demo") and (dirs or files)
                           for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(root_dir))
```

This will also return `True` if the target directory is contained *directly* in the root directory, or if it is nested deeper in subdirectories of subdirectories. Not entirely clear from your question if this is intended, or if the target directory has to be in a direct subdirectory of the root directory.

Comment: There *are* python shells.

Comment: @AnnZen Well, I know, so? But even so you would usually not call a Python script to run in those a "shell script" like OP does in the question, thus the clarification.

Comment: So instead of saying terminal, you can say python shell.

Comment: @AnnZen Yes, I could say that, but why would I? Of course you can execute a Python script in a Python shell, that's why it's a Python shell. What I wanted to say is that is can be executed, using the Python interpreter, in any terminal, by which I meant the command line interface of any OS, be it `bash`, or `command.exe`, or whatever. Not that any of this has anything to do with the question...

Comment: Well, the OP might've meant python shell, and thought it was correct to call a script written there a shell script. So correcting it to python shell might be better than jumping to terminal.

Comment: @AnnZen Feel free to do so in your answer.

Comment: I do, but not too necessary.